# Given an integral of a function f(x) find an integral of f(x^2-1).

Tags: calculus, integration

[The question that haunts me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBHfK.png)

As the image shows

A graph of a function  $ y = f(x) $ is sketched on the axis below.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJVOy.png)

The value of  $ \int_\limits{-1}^{1} f(x^2-1) dx $ equals

Can you any of you guys help? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try finding an explicit formula for $f$

Answer (score 1):

we have

$$\int_{-1}^1f(x^2-1)dx=2\int_0^1f(x^2-1)dx$$

since the integrand is an even function.

we have on $[0,1],   f(x)=1-x$

and  on $[-1,0], f(x)=1+x.$

thus

$$x\in[0,1] \implies  x^2-1\in[-1,0]$$

$$\implies f(x^2-1)=1+x^2-1=x^2$$

$$\implies \int_{-1}^1f(x^2-1)dx=2\int_0^1 x^2dx$$

$$=\frac 23.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I completely spaced out on actually stating f(x)

Answer (score 0):

$y=x$ for $-1 \le x+1 \le 0$ and $y=-x$ for $0 < x+1 \le 1$

So we can define $g(x) = x+1$ and $h(x) = -x+1$ and say

$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x^{2}-1) $ = $\int_{-1}^{0} g(x^{2}-1) + \int_{0}^{1} h(x^{2}-1) $